# Scaling and incrementing non-zero elements of a NumPy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a NumPy matrix `C` and want create a copy of it `cPrime`, which has some operation of the original matrix to all non-zero values of it. In the code below, for each non-zero element of `C`, I multiply by 30 and then add 1:

```
import numpy as np

size = 6
C = np.zeros((size,size), dtype=int)

C[4][0] = 2
C[4][1] = 5
C[4][2] = 3
C[0][3] = 1
C[1][3] = 1
C[2][3] = 1
C[3][5] = 3

cPrime = np.zeros((size, size),dtype=int)
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        if C[i][j] != 0:
            cPrime[i][j] = C[i][j]*30 + 1
```

This code works, but it feels inefficient. I'm about 99% sure that there's a really efficient way to achieve this goal, maybe using a masked array, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a typical use case for [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
cPrime = np.where(C, C * 30 + 1, C)
```

This is about twice as fast as `(30 * C + 1) * (C != 0)` and generalizes more easily to other conditions.

Answer (score 2):

`cPrime = 30 * C + 1`, which uses [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), comes close.  Unfortunately, it adds 1 indiscriminately to every single element, even the elements that were originally zero.

`C != 0` gives you the indexes of all the locations you want to operate on:

> ```
> >>> C
> array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
>        [2, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0],
>        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
> >>> C != 0
> array([[False, False, False,  True, False, False],
>        [False, False, False,  True, False, False],
>        [False, False, False,  True, False, False],
>        [False, False, False, False, False,  True],
>        [ True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
>        [False, False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
> ```

Combining the two concepts, you can write either

```
cPrime = 30 * C + 1 * (C != 0)
```

or

```
cPrime = (30 * C + 1) * (C != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For really large sparse matrices, convert numpy dense to
[scipy.sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).
These store *only* the non-zeros
(well, 2 ints + 1 double, 24 bytes):

```
import scipy.sparse

S = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix( C )  # dense to sparse
print( "S: %s  %d non-0" % (S.shape, S.nnz) )
S *= 30
S.data += 1  # increment only the non-0
# Dense = S.toarray()  # sparse to dense
```

(Be careful, there are corner cases where sparse and numpy dense behave differently; SO has almost 1000 [questions/tagged/scipy+sparse-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scipy+sparse-matrix) .)